# NPM Not a single package import working after install, also not appearing in the list

Tags: npm, npm-install

For every package I install, it installs perfectly and gets added to my dependencys. Yet when I try to use it or import it into my code, not a single part gets found from it. It also does not apprear into my list when I do npm list . 
It does show in my explorer in the module folder. I have been trying to find a sollution for 3hrs now. 
I have tried every stackoverflow solution I found but nothing works. Removed the folders, re-did the installs, the init, etc. Tried different packages. Nothing seems to be working.
Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/request/lib/har.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in ' 
D:\Eigen\PlexRequest\node_modules\request\lib'
@ ./node_modules/request/lib/har.js 3:9-22
@ ./node_modules/request/request.js
@ ./node_modules/request/index.js
@ ./node_modules/imdb/lib/movies.js
@ ./node_modules/imdb/lib/imdb.js
@ ./node_modules/imdb/index.js
@ ./src/app.js

ERROR in ./node_modules/forever-agent/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'net' in 

'D:\Eigen\PlexRequest\node_modules\forever-agent'
 @ ./node_modules/forever-agent/index.js 6:10-24
 @ ./node_modules/request/request.js
 @ ./node_modules/request/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/imdb/lib/movies.js
 @ ./node_modules/imdb/lib/imdb.js
 @ ./node_modules/imdb/index.js
 @ ./src/app.js

ERROR in ./node_modules/tough-cookie/lib/cookie.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'net' in 'D:\Eigen\PlexRequest\node_modules\tough-cookie\lib'
 @ ./node_modules/tough-cookie/lib/cookie.js 32:10-24
 @ ./node_modules/request/lib/cookies.js
 @ ./node_modules/request/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/imdb/lib/movies.js
 @ ./node_modules/imdb/lib/imdb.js
 @ ./node_modules/imdb/index.js
 @ ./src/app.js

ERROR in ./node_modules/tunnel-agent/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'net' in 'D:\Eigen\PlexRequest\node_modules\tunnel-agent'
 @ ./node_modules/tunnel-agent/index.js 3:10-24
 @ ./node_modules/request/lib/tunnel.js
 @ ./node_modules/request/request.js
 @ ./node_modules/request/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/imdb/lib/movies.js
 @ ./node_modules/imdb/lib/imdb.js
 @ ./node_modules/imdb/index.js
 @ ./src/app.js

ERROR in ./node_modules/forever-agent/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'tls' in 'D:\Eigen\PlexRequest\node_modules\forever-agent'
 @ ./node_modules/forever-agent/index.js 7:10-24
 @ ./node_modules/request/request.js
 @ ./node_modules/request/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/imdb/lib/movies.js
 @ ./node_modules/imdb/lib/imdb.js
 @ ./node_modules/imdb/index.js
 @ ./src/app.js

ERROR in ./node_modules/tunnel-agent/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'tls' in 'D:\Eigen\PlexRequest\node_modules\tunnel-agent'
 @ ./node_modules/tunnel-agent/index.js 4:10-24
 @ ./node_modules/request/lib/tunnel.js
 @ ./node_modules/request/request.js
 @ ./node_modules/request/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/imdb/lib/movies.js
 @ ./node_modules/imdb/lib/imdb.js
 @ ./node_modules/imdb/index.js
 @ ./src/app.js
```

Comment: Can you show how you're doing the import?

Comment: @barro32 just like the API usage says: var imdb = require('imdb'); the fact that it does not show up in my list makes it seem its not installed at all/